# selecting only the element in the same div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i selec only the element in the same div with jquery

```js
$('.to-show').hide();

$('#offset').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "Custom") {

    $(this).closest('.wrapper').children('.to-show').toggle();
  } else {
    $('.to-show').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="to-click">


    <td class="value">
      <select id="offset" class="" name="attribute_offset" data-attribute_name="attribute_offset" data-show_option_none="yes">
        <option value="">Choose an option</option>
        <option value="15" selected="selected" class="attached enabled">15</option>
        <option value="Custom" class="attached enabled">Custom</option>
      </select> </td>


  </div>
  <div class="to-show">
    <div class="tc-cell tc-col-auto"><button type="button" class="button tm-section-link" data-title="Custom Offset" data-sectionid="61cc25f8bfe870.59019822">Custom Offset</button></div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="to-click">

    <td class="value">
      <select id="offset" class="" name="attribute_offset" data-attribute_name="attribute_offset" data-show_option_none="yes">
        <option value="">Choose an option</option>
        <option value="15" selected="selected" class="attached enabled">15</option>
        <option value="Custom" class="attached enabled">Custom</option>
      </select> </td>

  </div>
  <div class="to-show">

    <div class="tc-cell tc-col-auto"><button type="button" class="button tm-section-link" data-title="Custom Offset" data-sectionid="61cc25f8bfe870.59019822">Custom Offset</button></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

So this only work with first select option

How i can make it work with the second select option what i am missing here ?

i tried also   `$(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.to-show').toggle();`

but that did not work

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Having two elements with the same id is invalid html. Switch it to use class or another attribute. But you have a second problem with  `$('.to-show').hide();`, it is always hiding both `.to-show`.

```js
$('.to-show').hide();

$('.offset').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "Custom") {

    $(this).closest('.wrapper').children('.to-show').toggle();
  } else {
    $(this).closest('.wrapper').children('.to-show').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="to-click">


    <td class="value">
      <select id="offset" class="offset" name="attribute_offset" data-attribute_name="attribute_offset" data-show_option_none="yes">
        <option value="">Choose an option</option>
        <option value="15" selected="selected" class="attached enabled">15</option>
        <option value="Custom" class="attached enabled">Custom</option>
      </select> </td>


  </div>
  <div class="to-show">
    <div class="tc-cell tc-col-auto"><button type="button" class="button tm-section-link" data-title="Custom Offset" data-sectionid="61cc25f8bfe870.59019822">Custom Offset</button></div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="to-click">

    <td class="value">
      <select id="offset" class="offset" name="attribute_offset" data-attribute_name="attribute_offset" data-show_option_none="yes">
        <option value="">Choose an option</option>
        <option value="15" selected="selected" class="attached enabled">15</option>
        <option value="Custom" class="attached enabled">Custom</option>
      </select> </td>

  </div>
  <div class="to-show">

    <div class="tc-cell tc-col-auto"><button type="button" class="button tm-section-link" data-title="Custom Offset" data-sectionid="61cc25f8bfe870.59019822">Custom Offset</button></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks i saw this warning in jsfiddle but ignore